# How to change hours in the date in Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to know how to change the hour of a date.

For example, if the date is a string in the form "2015-06-06 00:00:00" I want to change the hour aspect so that it becomes "2015-06-06 07:00:00"

So simply, I'd like to parse Scala a string of the date, then change the hour of it.

Answer (score 1):

Given a date String pattern "2015-06-06 00:00:00", you wanna change the hour of it.

Two things you have to do: parse the String as Date which is involving **SimpleDateFormat**; Then modify the hour of it, **Calendar** gets lots of method for modifying the year, month..., so you may have a try.

Following is how I get it done.

```
import java.text.{ SimpleDateFormat, ParseException }
import java.util.{ Calendar, Date }

object ChangeHourOfDate extends App {

    // for formating date as the form you want
    val datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    def format(when: Date, pattern: String) =
        new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(when)

    implicit class StringToDateOpt(str: String) {
        def parse(str: String, pattern: String) = {
            val format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
            format.setLenient(false)
            try
                Some(format.parse(str))
            catch {
                case e: ParseException => None
            }
        }

        def hourChangedOpt(hourToSet: Int) = {
            parse(str, datePattern).map { original =>
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime)
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourToSet)
                calendar.getTime
            }
        }

    }

    // trigger the implicit, create an instance of StringToDateOpt, so you can invoke hourChangedOpt
    val result = "2015-06-06 10:00:00".hourChangedOpt(7)
        .map(format(_, datePattern)).getOrElse("")

    // 2015-06-06 07:00:00
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried this code. I didn't copy all of it, just the most important part. It works for the above string, but when I change the"2015-06-06 00:00:00" to    "2015-06-06 10:00:00", the hour doesn't go to 17, but still 7.

Comment: Changing "2015-06-06 00:00:00" to "2015-06-06 10:00:00" seems like adding 10  hours to the original date, what do you mean by "the hour doesn't go to 17, but still 7".

Comment: Oh i see. That's gotta be confusing. What i rlly meant was that when I call the HourChange time on "2015-06-06 10:00:00" (I parsed 7 for the integer) It comes back as "2015-06-06 07:00:00"

Comment: If what you actually want is "2015-06-06 10:00:00".hourChange(7) yields "2015-06-06 07:00:00", then my editted answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**We can make it very simple by the following:**

**SCALA CODE**

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
val input_timestamp = "2019-08-05T12:50:21.884+02:00"
val updated_time=input_timestamp.toDateTime + 2.hours + 45.minutes
println(updated_time)
```

**OUTPUT :** 2019-08-05T15:35:21.884+02:00

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the hour (add or subtract) then you'll want to convert your `String` to a `DateTime` format in order to get the correct new date and time.

If you just want to manipulate a `String` then `patch()` will do that.

```
"2015-06-06 00:00:00".patch(11,"07",2)  //res0: String = 2015-06-06 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simpleDateFormat class from java. google will help you.
NB you can also import the joda-time java jar, which is very rich in term of fonctionalities.

Comment: I've seen pple using this joda thing, but when i try to import it, it gives an error. Do I need to download anything to use jodatime on scala?

Answer (score 0):

Samuel,

Try adding hours like this.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
  DateTime year2000 = dt.withYear(2000);
  DateTime twoHoursLater = dt.plusHours(2);
```

This link has a good description.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html